# Для элемента update требуется действительный deletecommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Доброго времени суток! 
Возникла следующая проблема, при работе с `SqlDataAdapter`.
Я прописал команды (`Delete`,`Insert`,`Update`) для адаптера и они прекрасно работают, НО если осуществляю конкретный поиск записи в таблице(`select*from... where...`), и пытаюсь удалить эту запись, то мне выдает следующую ошибку:

> для элемента update требуется действительный deletecommand, при
>   передаче коллекции DataRow c удаленными строками.

Comment: `Adapter` имеет четыре типа команд (`SelectCommand`, `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` и `DeleteCommand`). В каждом из этих параметров прописывается запрос, либо хранимая процедура.
У Вас отсутствует текст в `DeleteCommand` или `UpdateCommand` судя по всему. Нужно бы привести свои команды прописанные.

Comment: Просто очень странно, что оно Вам валит эту ошибку. Что-то подобное встречал, по-моему когда в команде использовал не первичный ключ, а обычный не ключевой аттрибут, но это было давно. Поэтому просил привести команды в вопросе.

Comment: а где прописаны эти команды? В каком именно методе?

Comment: Ну, в принципе не страшно, я бы вынес вообще в `Window_Load`, чтобы избежать перетирания данных. А по поводу ошибки, по всей видимости твой `DeleteCommand` не удовлетворяет некоторым условиям

Comment: Если у тебя `id` первичный ключ, который уникален, зачем все остальные проверки? Это относится к `UpdateCommand`  и `DeleteCommand`

Comment: Вот я тебе писал по поводу первичного ключа, была похожая ошибка. Убери лишние проверки, оставь только первичный ключ. Попробуй.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, сейчас проверю.

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, хорошо, учту.

Comment: Вы добавляли большой кусок кода, а потом его удалили. Он относился к новому вопросу?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет скорее к этому, я могу его вернуть, мне не сложно. Просто тут и без него ясно в чем дело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Дело совсем не в DeleteCommand и не в PK, CLR просто запутал меня данным сообщение. Дело было в том, что в обработчике кнопки "поиск", я переопределял существующий adapter, а надо было создать новый. Который заполняет, тот же DataSet. Спасибо Denis, в том что помог разобраться.